# Find invalid character check against string array in C#

Tags: c#, string, linq

I would like to check invalid character against string array to UrlEncode. How can I achieve using LINQ?

Here is my code:

```
string str = "myname@gmail.comAndIhave$5000";
List<string> invalidChars = new List<string> { "@", "$" }
if (str.IndexOf(invalidChars) >= 0)  // put linq to loop
{ str = System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(str); }
```

Pls advice!

Comment: Why not just call `UrlEncode` anyway? It's far less hassle than your pre-check.

Comment: Why do you think there exists a solution with LINQ? Why do you think this approach would be better than your current one?

Comment: Why not use regex  
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Actually, I am trying to save the string as Key in NoSQL database but it has character limitation. So I would like check only specific char which can't be accepted by the database as a key so that I can save some of the character which is generated by UrlEncode.

Comment: @SiThu Why don't you just call `UrlEncode` then? You don't save any time by performing the same loop that UrlEncode would do to check for invalid characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Any` and `Contains`:

```
string str = "mynamegmail.comAndIhave5000";
List<string> invalidChars = new List<string> { "@", "$" };
if (invalidChars.Any(invalid => str.Contains(invalid))) { 
        // do work
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert of your string to List of string and then you compare both list of string that invalid characters are exist or not,

```
string str = "myname@gmail.comAndIhave$5000";
List<string> invalidChars = new List<string> { "@", "$" };

var strList = str.Select(c => c.ToString());

if (strList.Any(invalidChars.Contains))
{
   //Found
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of many possible solutions:

```
var str = "myname@gmail.comAndIhave$5000";

var invalidChars = new[] { '@', '$' };

var invalidCharsFound = str.Intersect (invalidChars);

bool hasInvalidChars = invalidCharsFound.Any ();

invalidCharsFound.Dump (); // LinqPad
hasInvalidChars.Dump ();
```

[image: Code result]